# Extract rows from a dataframe using a list of n elements

Tags: r

I'm working on this dataframe:

```
Col0 <- c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF")
Col1 <- c(2,4,2,6,1,1)
Col2 <- c(3,3,2,1,3,4)
Col3 <- c(2,2,3,4,6,6)
Col4 <- c(1,3,3,1,2,1)
Col5 <- c(2,1,1,1,1,4)
Col6 <- c(2,4,2,5,4,4)
Col7 <- c(3,3,2,1,0,9)
Col8 <- c(2,2,3,4,5,4)
Col9 <- c(1,3,3,2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(Col0,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9)
```

That will be called in a function, to which will be passed a string of value belonging to the Col0.
I need to create a new df where the rows are the value extracted from the beginning one:

```
f<- function(dataframe, stringval){
listval<- strsplit(stringval,"-") [[1]] 
row1<- dataframe[dataframe[1]==listval[[1]],]
row2<- dataframe[dataframe[1]==listval[[2]],]
row3<- dataframe[dataframe[1]==listval[[3]],]
finaldf<- rbind(row1,row2,row3)
return(finaldf)
}
fmatr<- f(df,"AA-CC-DD")
```

The problem is that stringval, that in this case has dimension 3, can be of any dimension, and i don't know how to generalize the formula and make it usable with any input dimension.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does `stringval` have to be a "character"? You could use something like `f = function(x, ...) x[x[[1]] %in% c(...), ]` and call it as `f(df, "AA", "CC", "DD")`, though if your "f" just subsets, you can use, directly, `df[df[[1]] %in% c("AA", "CC", "DD"), ]`

Comment: follow alexis_laz comment instead of this clumsy approach. Built a function to decompose stringval in a vector of values with `strsplit` and pipe this in your new function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could simplify your function, while also making it more flexible in terms of the length of `stringval`.

```
f1 <- function(dataframe, stringval) { 

  ids <- unlist(strsplit(stringval, "-")) # Create vector of letters
  finaldf <- dataframe[dataframe[,1] %in% ids,] # Use them to subset 1st col
  return(finaldf)

}

# For example:
f1(df, "AA-CC-FF-EE")
#  Col0 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9
#1   AA    2    3    2    1    2    2    3    2    1
#3   CC    2    2    3    3    1    2    2    3    3
#5   EE    1    3    6    2    1    4    0    5    2
#6   FF    1    4    6    1    4    4    9    4    2
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. When i'll reach the score to vote i'll rate your answer up